# Noob question on image color space editing

Tags: color

I'm new to Mathematica so this will be probably a dumb question. I want to convert an image to [LMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LMS_color_space) color space and edit its channel. I think that what I have to do is import the image and use `ColorConvert` to get XYZ channels, use the inverse the matrix (XYZ to LMS) provided by Wikipedia, change the LMS values and then convert back to xyz inverting the previous matrix.
How should I write the code?

Comment: You use Import to get the image, convert using ColorConvert, then map to the new space using a mapping that you will have to define. Normally, you can expect to get help by showing the effort you have made and where you are getting stuck.